# Write a program to remove trailing blanks and tabs from each line of input, and to delete entirely blank lines

Tags: beginner, c

Continuing to slowly progress through `The C Programming Language` by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie.

The code I came up with below is for `Exercise 1-18 - Write a program to remove trailing blanks and tabs from each line of input and to delete entirely blank lines`.

Feedback is much appreciated. In particular, I would like to know:

1. How would you go about keeping track of the dynamic changing size of `curLine` and increasing its size should the current line eclipse 1000 bytes.
2. The `charCount` output for each line in the output seems to be 1 less than what is displayed in Vim for character count. Why is that? How can I ensure that the character count output in my code is not off by one?

```c
//  Exercise 1-18. Write a program to remove trailing blanks and tabs from each line of input, and to delete entirely blank lines.

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;
    int charCount = 0;
    char curLine[1000];

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        curLine[charCount] = c;
        if (c == '\n') {
            // Skip entirely blank lines
            if (charCount > 1) {
                // reduce charCount for trailing blanks and tabs ahead of printing
                int temp = charCount;
                for (int i = temp; curLine[i] == ' ' || curLine[i] == '\t' || curLine[i] == '\n'; i--) {
                    charCount--;
                }
                // print the line
                for (int i = 0; i < charCount + 1; i++) {
                    printf("%c", curLine[i]);
                }
                // Printing charCount to ensure trailing spaces, tabs, and entirely blank lines are removed
                printf("\nChar count after triming line: %i\n", charCount);
            }
            charCount = 0;
        } else {
            charCount++;
            curLine[charCount] = c;
        }
    }
    // If last line ends on a space instead of new line
    if (charCount > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < charCount; i++) {
            printf("%c", curLine[i]);
        }
        // Printing charCount to ensure trailing spaces, tabs, and entirely blank lines are removed
        printf("\n%i\n", charCount);
    }
}
```

**Updates**

- Edited code in response to `vnp` comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code doesn't work as required. All the trailing spaces and table are still in the output. To see it, prepare a `test` file with trailing spaces, run `./your_program < test > out`, then `od -b out` and observe that all the `o4o` bytes are there. The reason is that `curLine[tmp]` immediately is neither space nor tab (it is a newline), and the trimming loop does not run. VTC

Comment: Updated the code @vnp - also, thanks so much for the `od` command suggestion. It is SUPER helpful :) I also added another question relating to my `charCount` output being off by one.

Comment: iamericfletcher, With line `"  \n"`, what should happen?  What happens first, line reduction or the empty line filtering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would you go about keeping track of the dynamic changing size of curLine and increasing its size should the current line eclipse 1000 bytes.

One can code for that, yet consider growing an input buffer to any size allows a nefarious user to overwhelm memory resources.

Often, it is simply reasonable to limit input length to some large value and treat huge lines as foolish input or an attack **and** detect overlong lines.

Consider `BUFSIZ` from `<stdio.h>`.  "`BUFSIZ` which expands to an integer constant expression that is the size of the buffer used by the `setbuf`
function;"  "The value of the macro BUFSIZ shall be at least 256."  C17dr 7.21.

Sample:

```
char curLine[BUFSIZ];

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (charCount >= BUFSIZ - 1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Overly long line ignored.\n");
      while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        ;
      }

    curLine[charCount] = c;
    charCount = 0;
    continue;
  }
  ...
```

---

> The `charCount` output for each line in the output seems to be 1 less than what is displayed in Vim for character count. Why is that? How can I ensure that the character count output in my code is not off by one?

`charCount` fails to  include the `'\n'` in its summation.

---

Other

**`int` vs. `char`**

OP correctly uses `int ch` instead of `char ch` to store the typically 257 different possible responses from `getchar()`.

**Code re-use**

Since processing a line inside the loop is like processing the line after the loop, consider a helper function.
It appears the *char count after trimming line* includes the `'\n'`.

```
void process_line(int length, const char *line) {
  // Only process and print line if not empty and not just a \n
  if (length > 0 && line[0] != '\n') {
    bool eol_found = false;
    if (line[length-1] == '\n') {
      length--;
      eol_found = true;
    }

    // remove trailing blanks and tabs
    while (length > 0 && (line[length-1] == ' ' || line[length-1] == '\t')) {
      length--;
    }

    // %.*s prints a character array up to the supplied length or a null character
    printf("%.*s\n", length, line);
    printf("char count after trimming line: %i\n", length + eol_found);
  }
}
```

**Simplification**

In this sample code, `curLine[]` does not become a *string* as a *null character* is not appended.  Instead *charCount* is used to control print width.

```
int c;
int charCount = 0;
char curLine[BUFSIZ];

while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
  if (charCount >= BUFSIZ) {
    ; // As above error handling
  }
  curLine[charCount++] = c;
  if (c == '\n') {
    process_line(charCount, curLine);
    charCount = 0;
  }
}

process_line(charCount, curLine);
```

Comment: `BUFSIZ` on my Linux machine is `8192` bytes! Would you say having an upper bound of `8192` bytes is ok? It's larger than the `1000` byte buffer I was using, but I'm curious if `8192` is long enough for bad actors to overwhelm memory resources? I assume not.

Also, I'm curious to know what situations would need 8192 characters on a line anyway?

Comment: @iamericfletcher `BUFSIZ` tends to be scaled to system resources, so declaring another buffer of `BUFSIZ` is not something that is hardly expected to overwhelm system resources.  Synthesized text input (e.g. from another program) are a somewhat common source of _long_ lines.

Answer (score 2):

## General Observations

This code is very inefficient. As you become more experienced you will learn to separate input, output and processing. Processing during input and output makes the code more complex and that means the code is harder to read, write and maintain. You might want to implement functions to read, write and process the characters.

Another thing that makes the code inefficient is that it uses `printf("%c", VAR)` in a loop. It would be better to read in a line of input, then remove any trailing blanks and tabs from the line, and then print the entire line as a string using `printf("%s", curLine);`. The `printf()` function is a very expensive function to call in terms of processing time. In the current implementation [putchar()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/putchar) is a more efficient function to use for output.

Rather than 1000 characters for for curLine, it would be more common to use 1K or 1024 characters since this is a power of 2.

## Magic Numbers

The number `1000` is a Magic Number, it might be better to create symbolic constants for it to make the code more readable and easier to maintain. These numbers may be used in many places and being able to change them by editing only one line makes maintained easier.

Numeric constants in code are sometimes referred to as [Magic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), because there is no obvious meaning for them. There is a discussion of this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad).

Comment: "The printf() function is a very expensive function to call in terms of processing time. In the current implementation (`printf("%c", curLine[i])`) `putchar()` is a more efficient function to use for output." perpetuates a micro-optimization concern that is irrelevant with modern compilers.  Good compilers will emit similar code for both.  The point about a single `printf()` call is good.